# Parse complex <li> tag using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage with following code:

```
<li> 
<a href="/wiki/Thalassery" title="Thalassery">Thalassery</a> (<a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Malayalam_language" title="Malayalam language">Malayalam</a>: <span lang="ml">തലശ്ശേരി</span>), from 
<i>Tellicherry</i></li>
         <li><a href="/wiki/Thanjavur" title="Thanjavur">Thanjavur</a> (<a href="/wiki/Tamil_language" title="Tamil language">Tamil</a>: <span lang="ta">தஞ்சாவூர்</span>), from British name <i>Tanjore</i></li>
         <li><a href="/wiki/Thane" title="Thane">Thane</a> (<a href="/wiki/Marathi_language" title="Marathi language">Marathi</a>: <span lang="mr">ठाणे</span>), from British name <i>Tannah</i></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Thoothukudi" title="Thoothukudi">Thoothukudi</a> (<a href="/wiki/Tamil_language" title="Tamil language">Tamil</a>: <span lang="ta">தூத்துக்குடி</span>), from <i>Tuticorin</i> and its short form <i>Tuty</i></li>
```

I need to parse the output such that the result will be extracting words like: Thalassery, Tellicherry, Thanjavur, Tanjore, Thane, Tannah, Thoothukudi, Tuticorin

Can anyone please help with this

Comment: Did you try `result = soup.findAll("i")`?

Comment: Please post some code that you have actually tried before posting for help. You would need to get the <li> tag then process the data again to get the information you need. I am giving you a downvote for not showing any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.findAll()` to get all the `li` elements and use `find()` `'a'` and `'i'` tag

```
for item in soup.findAll('li'):
    print(item.find('a').text,item.find('i').text)

>>>
Thalassery Tellicherry
Thanjavur Tanjore
Thane Tannah
Thoothukudi Tuticorin
```

Comment: This works fine for <a> tag for <i> tag it throws error:


                ----> 4         print(item.find('i').text)

               AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

If i just give:

print(item.find('i'))

It shows the values but with <i> tags as follows:

<i>Panjim</i>

How do I extract text only and not the tags. I know .text should have worked but it throws error as mentioned above

Comment: This works fine for <a> tag for <i> tag it throws error: ----> 4 print(item.find('i').text) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' If i just give: print(item.find('i')) It shows the values but with <i> tags as follows: <i>Panjim</i> How do I extract text only and not the tags. I know .text should have worked but it throws error as mentioned above

Comment: the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ` means you are getting an `blank`. check condition to avoid that case

Answer (score 0):

Try simplified_scrapy's solution, its fault tolerance

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html='''
<li> 
<a href="/wiki/Thalassery" title="Thalassery">Thalassery</a> (<a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Malayalam_language" title="Malayalam language">Malayalam</a>: <span lang="ml">തലശ്ശേരി</span>), from 
<i>Tellicherry</i></li>
         <li><a href="/wiki/Thanjavur" title="Thanjavur">Thanjavur</a> (<a href="/wiki/Tamil_language" title="Tamil language">Tamil</a>: <span lang="ta">தஞ்சாவூர்</span>), from British name <i>Tanjore</i></li>
         <li><a href="/wiki/Thane" title="Thane">Thane</a> (<a href="/wiki/Marathi_language" title="Marathi language">Marathi</a>: <span lang="mr">ठाणे</span>), from British name <i>Tannah</i></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Thoothukudi" title="Thoothukudi">Thoothukudi</a> (<a href="/wiki/Tamil_language" title="Tamil language">Tamil</a>: <span lang="ta">தூத்துக்குடி</span>), from <i>Tuticorin</i> and its short form <i>Tuty</i></li>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
lis = doc.lis
print ([(li.a.text,li.i.text if li.i else '') for li in lis])
```

Result:

```
[('Thalassery', 'Tellicherry'), ('Thanjavur', 'Tanjore'), ('Thane', 'Tannah'), ('Thoothukudi', 'Tuticorin')]
```